# A simple question on changing bounce properties

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to model a ball. I'm not having any luck with making it bounce.  I try to set the restitution coefficient in my URDF code, but when I look at the properties of the ball in Gazebo (ball1 -> ball -> link -> collision -> surface) the restitution_coefficient is still equal to zero.

I'm running Fuerte (which should correspond to Gazebo 1.0.2) on Ubuntu 12.04.

The URDF:

```
 <robot name="my_ball">
  <link name="ball">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <mass value="0.0027" />
      <inertia  ixx="0.00000072" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="0.00000072"  iyz="0.0"  izz="0.00000072" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".040" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius=".040" />
      </geometry>
      <surface>
           <bounce restitution_coefficient = "1"/>
      </surface>
    </collision>

  </link>
  <gazebo reference="ball">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <kd value = "100">
    <kp value = "999999">
        <mu1>1</mu1>
    <mu2>1</mu2>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

I'm loading the ball using:

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/ballmodel.urdf -urdf -z 10 -x 1 -y -2 -model ball1
```

I've also tried a few different tags for the restitution coefficient including:

```
<surface>
...
<bounce restitution_coefficient="0.5" threshold="0.00"/>
...
</surface>
```

And:

```
<surface>
...
  <bounce>
       <restitution_coefficient="1"/>
   </bounce>
...
</surface>
```

and:

```
<surface>
...    
   <bounce>
       <restitution_coefficient> 1 </restitution_coefficient>
    </bounce>
</surface>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/678/a-simple-question-on-changing-bounce-properties/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2014-05-21**:
@Ben B which URDF code worked finally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's 3 parameters that must be set to enable bouncing. restitution___coefficient must be greater than 0, the bounce threshold must be small, and max_vel must be greater than zero.

Gazebo computes the relative velocity between two bodies in contact. If the relative velocity normal to the contact surface is greater than the bounce threshold, then a bounce may occur, but the bounce velocity will be limited by the max_vel parameter.

Here's an example sdf file that works in gazebo 1.3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="default">
    <include><uri>model://ground_plane</uri></include>
    <include><uri>model://sun</uri></include>
    <model name="ball">
      <pose>0 0 10.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.5</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <bounce>
              <restitution_coefficient>0.5</restitution_coefficient>
              <threshold>0</threshold>
            </bounce>
            <contact>
              <ode>
                <max_vel>10</max_vel>
              </ode>
            </contact>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.5</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice_ly](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/52118/alice_ly/) on 2021-08-15**:
Thanks a lot, and I have some problems in bouncing accuracy, I use a same scene which simulates the elastic collision and when I reset the scene the wield thing happend, which is that the two attempts bounce totally different.
I have seen some answers saying that we can change the iteration to make the computation of Gazebo more accurately, but I haven't got idea how to change it, have any friends tried that, if so, please give me some ideas, thank you very much!!